# Perché questa frutta si chiama "tabacchiera"?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Durante un recente viaggio in Italia ho scoperto che la frutta della fotografia si chiama "tabacchiera", parola che mi è sembrata molto curiosa.

[image]

([Fonte della immagine](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Prunus-persica-1060223.JPG))

Beh, perlomeno è così come la chiamava il fruttivendolo perché non ho trovato questa accezione in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Si trova [qualcosa su Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesca_tabacchiera), ma non so fino a che punto le informazioni che si includono là sono affidabili (la prima cosa che si vede è una frase evidenziata e indicata come "senza fonte").

La mia domanda è: da dove proviene questo nome, "tabacchiera", per questa frutta? Veramente si chiama così perché assomiglia a una tabacchiera? (personalmente non riesco a immaginare una scatoletta per tabacco con la forma di questa frutta). In spagnolo usiamo il termine  ["paraguayo"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rqd7NAW) per designarla (in catalano sono "paraguaians", ma non so perché è una di quelle parole che, perlomeno a Barcellona, quasi tutti dicono in castigliano): non so neanche da dove proviene questo nome (e non ho trovato nulla al riguardo), forse dovrei chiederlo in Spanish.SE.

Comment: Questo non risponde alla tua domanda, ma lo Zingarelli registra questo uso: alla voce “pèsca” si legge tra l'altro “_pesca tabacchiera_, varietà a forma schiacciata, profumo intenso, polpa bianca, succosa e dolce, coltivata in aree limitate e spec. in Sicilia”.

Comment: Finalmente ho deciso di porre la [domanda su Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27170/19075).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Su [questo blog](https://soccorsoverde.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/la-tabacchiera/) ho trovato:

> È la pesca “Tabacchiera” così chiamata per la sua forma piatta, a
>   disco, che ricorda appunto quella di una tabacchiera.

In [questo altro blog](http://www.civiltadelbere.com/pesca-tabacchiera/) invece

> Il suo nome scientifico è *Prunis persica*, varietà *platycarpa* ossia dal
>   corpo piatto: la tabacchiera appartiene a pieno diritto alla famiglia
>   delle pesche. Fu introdotta in Europa attraverso la Persia, pur se le
>   sue origini sono cinesi, come per diverse piante della famiglia delle
>   Rosacee ormai diventate comuni in Europa quali il ciliegio e il melo.
>
> **In Sicilia l’antica pesca tabacchiera** 
> La sua è una storia curiosa. È opinione comune che la si chiami *tabacchiera* nel Sud Italia e
>   *saturnia* o *saturnina* al Centro Nord. Le forme più antiche di questa
>   pianta si sono sempre chiamate tabacchiera.

Come utilmente sottolineato da @DaG anche su [Zanichelli](http://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/parola-del-giorno/2011/08/16/la_parola_del_giorno__pesca/) si può trovare un riferimento:

> ***pesca tabacchiera***, varietà a forma schiacciata, profumo intenso, polpa
>   bianca, succosa e dolce, coltivata in aree limitate della Sicilia e
>   della Romagna.

Comment: Veramente io ero nel nord Italia.

Comment: Anche io sapevo che si chiama così per via della forma larga e piatta http://www.candidooperti.it/images/articoli-CULTURA-immagini/tabacchiere-argento-oggetti/F-Tabacchiere-01.jpg